# php zend_extension getting ignored when self-compiling php

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, zend

I am trying to load Zend Optimizer into my self-compiled php.

Here is how i compile my php:

```
wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.6.tar.gz
tar xvfz php-5.2.6.tar.gz
cd php-5.2.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
make install
```

However, the zend_extension directive in php.ini is getting completely ignored. If I use a non-existent path i still don't even get a error message. 
When using a pre-compiled php library everything is working fine.

In php.ini I also set

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
```

error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log is only getting written when a error in a php-file occurs.

In apache.conf i set

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel debug
```

I also tried compiling with `--disable-maintainer-zts --disable-safe-mode` which was mentioned on another website. I choose php-5.2.6 because it is the version of the (working) pre-compiled php, but i also tried php-version 5.2.16.

Comment: Just out of interest, when you run `php -i` from the command line, have you checked that it's loading the `php.ini` file you thought you were loading?

Comment: For example: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc` 
`Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini` 
`Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d` 
`Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/apc.ini` etc

Comment: Also look for something that looks like : `Zend Extension => 220090626` `Zend Extension Build => API220090626,NTS` on that first page or two of results. Posting the output of `php -i` into your question would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Solution:

According to the [Zend Optimizer user guide](http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Optimizer-User-Guide-v330-new.pdf)

> The Zend Optimizer will not run if the following PHP settings are enabled:
>
> - **Debug Mode** - Check that your PHP was compiled in non-debug mode - This can be checked by looking at the top part of the phpinfo() function output and checking "Debug Build" row (ZEND_DEBUG in older PHP versions) - it should say "no".
> - **Thread Safety** - Check that your PHP was compiled in ZTS mode for Windows and non-ZTS mode for UNIX. This can be checked by looking at the top part of the phpinfo() function and checking "Thread Safety" row - it should say "disabled" for Unix and "enabled" for Windows.
> - **Enable Versioning** - Check that your PHP was compiled without the Enable Versioning setting. This can be checked by looking at the top part of the phpinfo() function and checking to see if a row called "--enable-versioning" exists in the Configure Command section - if it does exists the PHP should be compiled without this option.

The configure options --disable-zts and --disable-maintainer-zts (which should turn of Thread Safety mode) do **NOT** exist in PHP 5.2.x

You can control the Thread-Safety mode by doing the following:

> I found it, it was because installing apache2-dev package on my system (Ubuntu) automatically installs apache2-thread-dev whose apxs2 tells the PHP build system to build with thread-safety on. Therefore, the solution was to directly install apache2-prefork-dev package. (Credits for this go to [amr-mostafa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43597/amr-mostafa))

The behavior described above does also apply to debian. So removing apache-tread-dev and installing apache2-prefork-dev did the deal!